# Битрикс оплата счета частями

Tags: php, битрикс

Как реализовать оплату заказа частями, использую обработчик счет? Например, сумма заказа 10 000 руб, заказчик может оплатить любую сумму, например 3623 руб.

Как сформировать счет на эту сумму?

Comment: Что такое - "сумма заказа 10 000 человек"? Добавте в вопрос код.

Comment: @0xdb битрикс же. Другого кода ещё нет, очевидно :)

Comment: @0xdb поставил запятую. Насчет кода, его пока что нет, я в поисках класса или метода, надеюсь встроенного в битрикс, от которого смогу оттолкнутся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете свою форму оплаты. Смотрите если введенная сумма меньше той, что человек должен заплатить при помощи АПИ удаляете неоплаченную запись оплаты. И вместо нее формируете две новых. На оплачиваемую сумму и на остаток. Далее запускаете стандартный ход оплаты. Возможно проще (с точки зрения разработки) сделать двухшаговую оплату: задаем сумму и переходим к оплате.

АПИ работы с заказом достаточно хорошо расписано [здесь](https://mrcappuccino.ru/blog/post/work-with-order-bitrix-d7)